# How to append html using jquery with less than character

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display and append a string HTML with "<" character on it. But it somehow breaks the line by treating it as HTML tag.

```
$(this).html.append('<a href="javascript:void(0)"> < Click here  with</a>');
```

How Can I fix this?

Comment: what is the structure of `$(this)`

Comment: Use the corresponding html entity for < which is &lt;

Comment: If this is really the code than it should throw a TypeError. And for the `<` character, use the html entity `&lt;`

Comment: The "< Click here with" is actually dynamic pass from a parameter.I need to replace the "<" with &lt; becfore I will append it. Thanks It sure helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&#060;` or `&lt;`instead of the `<` symbol.

See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
var divValue = $('div').html();
divValue=divValue+'<a href="javascript:void(0)"> < Click here  with</a>';
$('div').html(divValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>link</div>
```

Also you can use `&lt;` to specify <.

Comment: `.html()` is not the same as `.append()`

Comment: @Andreas answer updated!!